# How do you vertically center a table view that has a variable number of rows?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a variable number of rows, rather than being a static height.

How can I vertically center this variable-height table view within a UIView?

Comment: What is your question..can you make it more specific ?

Comment: You can do that by specifying the correct frame for your tableview. With what you have asked,this is the max one can tell.

Answer (score 0):

One cheap and easy way to vertically center text in table view cells is
you could subclass NSTextFieldCell, and for each table column set it to
use the subclass cell.  In the subclass, intercepting the rectangle
into which it draws the cell contents is a simple matter: override the
drawInteriorWithFrame method, making some adjustments to the frame,
then call the super method.

```
- (void)drawInteriorWithFrame:(NSRect)cellFrame
                        inView:(NSView *)controlView {
    // Adjust the cell frame rect so it appears vertically centered.
    NSSize contentSize = [self cellSize];
    cellFrame.origin.y += (cellFrame.size.height - contentSize.height)
/ 2.0f;
    cellFrame.size.height = contentSize.height;
    // Do whatever it is it does...
    [super drawInteriorWithFrame:cellFrame inView:controlView];
}
```

Comment: Oh wait do you want to center the Table View itself. If so then I have no clue